# using drush php-eval db_query() are there differences with db_query() from code?

Tags: 7, drush, database

I think the answer should be easy but I can't find it.

maybe I've been put in the wrong direction finding sites telling how to clear my flood table like so:

```
drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `flood`");'
```

But I think is should be like this so it also works for prefixed tables:

```
drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `{flood}`");'
```

Or does db_query() works different in drush php-eval?
As far as I know it just executes php but does it has the drupal 'library' available or not?

Now I could just try and see what happens but I think it's good to really know if there's a difference or not in running db_query() from drush or from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this for definite but conceptually speaking, if Drush *didn't* use a standard Drupal bootstrap to perform these tasks it would have to re-implement all of that functionality itself.

Drush uses your site's settings.php file for the database connection, which leads me to believe it will also have access to things like `$db_prefix`.

I think it's safe to say exactly the same thing is happening when you run `db_query()` from Drush as if you run it from any other bootstrapped instance of Drupal.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct for php-eval: the code will execute in the same environment that it does when running from within a Drupal site, so prefixed tables will be handled for {flood} and similar.  However, please note that the sql-query command avoids modifying your query in any way unless you specify the --db-prefix option.  The sql-query version of the above example would therefore be: `drush sql-query --db-prefix 'DELETE FROM {flood};'` (please excuse quoting variation; stack exchange code filter in effect)